# Javascript string replace last ocurrence

Tags: javascript, string, replace

Why last 'AND' is not removed/replaced?

```
obj.where_str ="CD_MAQ LIKE '%AA%'  AND";
  obj.where_str = $.trim(obj.where_str).replace(obj.where_str.lastIndexOf("AND"), " ");
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why last 'AND' is not removed/replaced?

Because you are trying to replace the output of `lastIndexOf` which is an 
`integer`

Use `replace` with regex

```
obj.where_str = obj.where_str.replace( /(AND)\s*$/, "" )
```

`/(AND)\s*$/` will replace *AND* near the end of the string may (or may not) be followed by *spaces*.

Comment: Thanks. And if i want to do something but for the beginning ?

Comment: You mean AND at the beginning? You can either use `.replace( /^(AND)/, "" )` where `/^` asserts beginning of string. Or simple `.trim().substring(3)` will do.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```js
var obj = {};
  
obj.where_str ="CD_MAQ LIKE '%AA%'  AND";
var lastIndex = obj.where_str.lastIndexOf(" ");

obj.where_str = $.trim(obj.where_str.substring(0, lastIndex));
console.log(obj.where_str);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

`lastIndexOf()` returns an index.

You could use that index to select the substring in which you wish to replace `"AND"`

Would give something like this

```
str.substr(0, str.lastIndexOf("AND")) + "" + str.substr(str.lastIndexOf("AND") + "".length)
```

---